KServe minReplicas vs knativemin-scale
I am trying to understand KServe minReplicas parameter vs Knative min-scale (same for maxReplicas vs max-scale).
Looks like both are controlling the same behavior.
I was looking for some documentation that would provide an explanation of why we need minReplicas on top of min-scale and if there's a difference between the two - but didn't manage to find any.

Got an answer on the KServe Slack channel.
Both are indeed controlling the same behavior. If min/maxRelpicas are defined they override min/max-scale.
See relevant code
